# Как узнать размер одномерного массива в C#?

Tags: c#, массивы

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, как можно узнать размер такого массива:

```
double[] height = { 98.5, 100,  100, 100.5, 200, 200.3, 204, 210.8 };
```

Comment: height.Length?

Comment: Уточните что именно вы хотите узнать, "размер массива" или "размерность массива"?

Answer (score 4):

```
height.Length
```

Или я что-то не понял?)

Answer (score 1):

Вам, вероятно, нужен либо `height.Length` либо [`height.Rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank.aspx).

Comment: это наверно для динамических массивов, для такого не подходит..подчеркивает.

Comment: Никогда не слышал про "динамические массивы" в C#. ) А если серьезно &ndash; то могли бы ошибку процитировать.

Comment: Вот


     int g = speed.Lenght;
    Error 1 A field initializer cannot reference the non-  static field, method, or property 'Del.FormMem.speed' C:\Users\Анна\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\КП1\КП1\Form1.cs 24 17 КП1

Comment: Эта ошибка никак не относится к сабжу.

Comment: Вы не можете инициализировать поле не статичным свойством, методом или полем...
Вынесите инициализацию например, в конструктор класса.

    int g;
    double[] height = { 98.5, 100,  100, 100.5, 200, 200.3, 204, 210.8 };
    public class()
    {
        g = height.Length;
    }

Answer (score 1):

Верный ответ .length
А преимущество массивов перед списками - выигрыш в производительности, если заранее известен размер массива, или его изменяемость предсказуема.

В остальных случаях, List будет удобнее, но это не = быстрее.